# Cgroups - memory subsystem

Tags: process, memory, performance, cgroups

I want to set the `memory.limit_in_bytes` parameter for a control group and disable OOM, so processes freeze when the limit is reached. That said, I want to change that limit *dynamically* based on availability of memory. I managed to get a test process to reach the limit and it got paused (as expected), but when I tried to change the `memory.limit_in_bytes` with `echo` command I could not do it.

Can the memory limit change dynamically, so processes can resume their works?